# I am trying to use python 3 instead of python 2

Tags: python, macos, terminal, version

Currently in my mac terminal when I type `python --version` it says I am using python 2.7.x. I would like to change so that I am using python 3.8.x. How can I update this in terminal? Also, if I would like to go back to using python 2.7, is there a way to revert it?

Thanks!

Comment: What if you type `python3 --version` at the command line?

Answer (score 0):

- If Python 3 is installed, you should be able to run `python3`. If not, install the current distribution from their [website](https://www.python.org/downloads/).
- Python 2.7.x is always available via the alias `python2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install python3
```

will install python 3 and you can use `python3` command to run 3x version of python. If you want to use python 2x version you could either use virtualenv or you could just use `python2` to run your program with python 2x version.

If you want to implicitly specify that inside a file you could use

```
#!/bin/env python2.7
```

on top of the script to run the program with python 2.7 version.

As you see, there are many options for the same.

Comment: I did `brew install python3` and then was given this warning `Warning: python 3.7.7 is already installed, it's just not linked`
`You can use `brew link python` to link this version.` So I did `brew link python`, but that doesn't seem to have fixed the issue either...

Comment: I'm getting an error: `Error: Could not symlink bin/2to3`

Comment: brew link python. This command should link python to python3. Did you try it?

Comment: What is the error you are getting while using python3 command?